# JQuery/Ajax calls in a For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to put `("xxxxx").html(data)` in a for loop where the "xxxx" variable changes each time?

I honestly feel like I've tried everything. I'm trying to fill up an HTML table with JSONP data from a looping ajax call where the URL changes each time.  The same callback function is used every time, but, obviously, I keep overwriting the data that is to be sent to the HTML table tags because I can't figure out a way to dynamically change these variables.

Basically, I want the first time the callback function is called to store data in something like...

```
$("#p1_points").html(data_from_ajax_call)
```

The second time I want it to do...

```
$("#p2_points").html(data_from_ajax_call)
```

I've tried silly things like (inside a for loop) doing ...

```
$("#p" + i + "_points").html(data_from_ajax_call)
```

and all sorts of fun stuff, but it doesn't accept arguments of any kind...  So, any thoughts?  Is this trivial and I'm just over-thinking and under-sleeping it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATING FOR CLARITY

My ajax calls look like this...

```
for (var i = 0; i < thisweeksraiders.length; i++){
    $.ajax({
        "url":"http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/" + thisweeksraiders[i] + "?jsonp=myCallback",
        "type":"GET",
        "data": { fields: "items, professions, talents, progression"},
        "dataType":"jsonp",
        "contentType":"application/json",
        "jsonpCallback":"myCallback",
        "success":function(data1){
        }
    })
}
```

and my callback function looks like this...

```
function myCallback(data1) {
        //itemscounter += 1;
        var hascloak = "No";
        var possupgrades = 30;
        var offhandequipped = false;
        var tempupgrades = 0;
        var tierequipped = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < gearlist.length; i++){
            if (data1.items[(gearlist[i])].tooltipParams.upgrade)
                tempupgrades += data1.items[(gearlist[i])].tooltipParams.upgrade.current;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < tierlist.length; i++){
            if(data1.items[(tierlist[i])].tooltipParams.set)
                tierequipped += 1;
        }
        if (data1.items.offHand){
            tempupgrades += data1.items.offHand.tooltipParams.upgrade.current;
            offhandequipped = true;
        }
        if (offhandequipped)
            possupgrades = 32;
        if(data1.items[(gearlist[3])].quality == 5)
            hascloak = "Yes";
        $("#p1_cloak").html(hascloak);
        $("#p1_tier").html(tierequipped + "/5");
        $("#p1_achieve").html(data1.achievementPoints);
        $("#p1_iLevelE").html(data1.items.averageItemLevelEquipped);
        $("#p1_upgrades").html(tempupgrades + "/" + possupgrades);
        var totalnormalkills = 0;
        var totalheroickills = 0;
        var furthestboss = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < soobosslist.length; i++){
            totalnormalkills += data1.progression.raids[31].bosses[i].normalKills;
            totalheroickills += data1.progression.raids[31].bosses[i].heroicKills;
        }
        if (totalheroickills == 0){
            for (var i = 14; i > 0; i--){
                if (data1.progression.raids[31].bosses[i-1].normalKills > 0){
                    furthestboss = i + "N";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 14; i > 0; i--){
                if (data1.progression.raids[31].bosses[i-1].heroicKills > 0){
                    furthestboss = i + "H";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $("#p1_normalkills").html(totalnormalkills);
        $("#p1_heroickills").html(totalheroickills);
        $("#p1_xp").html(furthestboss);
        var classtemp;
        var colortemp;
        switch(data1.class){
        case 1: classtemp = "Warrior"; colortemp = "#C79C6E"; break;
        case 2: classtemp = "Paladin"; colortemp = "#F58CBA"; break;
        case 3: classtemp = "Hunter"; colortemp = "#ABD473"; break;
        case 4: classtemp = "Rogue"; colortemp = "#FFF569"; break;
        case 5: classtemp = "Priest"; colortemp = "#FFFFFF"; break;
        case 6: classtemp = "Death Knight"; colortemp = "#C41F3B"; break;
        case 7: classtemp = "Shaman"; colortemp = "#0070DE"; break;
        case 8: classtemp = "Mage"; colortemp = "#69CCF0"; break;
        case 9: classtemp = "Warlock"; colortemp = "#9482C9"; break;
        case 10: classtemp = "Monk"; colortemp = "#00FF96"; break;
        case 11: classtemp = "Druid"; colortemp = "#FF7D0A"; break;
        }
        $("#p1_classspec").html("<font color=" + colortemp + "><b>" + data1.name + "</b></font><font size='-1' color=" + colortemp + "><em> (" + data1.talents[0].spec.name + ")</em></font>");
        var profstemp = (data1.professions.primary[0].name + " & " + data1.professions.primary[1].name);
        $("#p1_profs").html(profstemp);
    }
```

So, basically, all the #p1 stuff I could put at the end of the function, but I'd like to change it all to $p2 to fill in the next row on my table.  The HTML should be obvious, but here it is...

```
<body>
<center>
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="p1_classspec">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_iLevelE">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_upgrades">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_cloak">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_tier">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_profs">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_achieve">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_normalkills">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_heroickills">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p1_xp">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="p2_classspec">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_iLevelE">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_upgrades">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_cloak">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_tier">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_profs">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_achieve">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_normalkills">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_heroickills">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p2_xp">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="p3_classspec">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_iLevelE">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_upgrades">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_cloak">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_tier">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_profs">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_achieve">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_normalkills">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_heroickills">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="p3_xp">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
```

If you follow this link, you'll see what I'm going for (this is not using the for loop).  I just want to drastically cut down on my code.

http://www.mynextbit.com/Pages/Wreckedified/test2.html

One more Update for Patrick...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < thisweeksraiders.length; i++){
            (function(index)
                window.jsonpCallbacks["myCallback" + index] = function(data){
                    myCallback(data,index);
                };
        })(i);
            $.ajax({
                "url":"http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/" + thisweeksraiders[i] + "?jsonp=jsonpCallbacks.myCallback" + i,
                "type":"GET",
                "data": { fields: "items, professions, talents, progression"},
                "dataType":"jsonp",
                "contentType":"application/json",
                "jsonpCallback":"jsonpCallbacks.myCallback"+i,
                "success":function(data1){
                }
            })
        }

    });
```

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean - are you rewriting the table body each time, or are you appending a new row?

Comment: I've updated with more info Geezer68, maybe that will clarify

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you loop looks something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   $.ajax({
    //
    success:function(data){
       $("#p" + i + "_points").html(data);
    }
   });
}
```

it will not work as `i` will end up being the last `i` value in the loop; You need something like below

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   (function(index){
      $.ajax({
       //
       success:function(data){
          $("#p" + index + "_points").html(data);
       }
      });
   })(i);
}
```

The closure along with the passing of `i` will keep number value for that call.

of course there will need to exist elements with ids 1-10 or whatever number you use so:

```
<element id="p1_points">
<element id="p2_points">
<element id="p3_points">
...
```

EDIT to account for JSONP callback:

modify myCallback() to be:

```
function myCallback(data,index)
```

and use the index to make your `"#p"+index+"_points"` etc ids

and then for the loop and ajax:

```
//Keeps track of the callbacks
//we will prepend 'jsonpCallbacks.' to the callback names
window.jsonpCallbacks = {};

for (var i = 0; i < thisweeksraiders.length; i++){
    (function(index){
      window.jsonpCallbacks["myCallback"+index] = function(data){
         myCallback(data,index);
      };
    })(i);
    $.ajax({
        "url":"http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/" + thisweeksraiders[i] + "?jsonp=jsonpCallbacks.myCallback"+i,
        "type":"GET",
        "data": { fields: "items, professions, talents, progression"},
        "dataType":"jsonp",
        "contentType":"application/json",
        "jsonpCallback":"jsonpCallbacks.myCallback"+i,
        "success":function(data1){
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna mess with this suggestion, I'll have to change a lot of code as I was hoping for a solution that would allow my to put a for loop inside my callback function, not nested in the success trigger.

Comment: @Bonedancer what callback function? Edit your question to show your loop and ajax calls so we can better help solve your problem.

Comment: @Bonedancer, sorry i forgot these were jsonp calls, i have edited my answer to help accommodate for this

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I'm working this out right now, will mark as correct as soon as possible.  Do you see anything wrong with your syntax on the window.jsonpCallbacks line?

Comment: My IDE is just showing one, that's all.  I'm trying to figure it out, I'm sure it's a matter of adapting it into the larger picture.

Comment: I'll mark it as correct, as I'm sure this will work the more I look into closures.  I'm pretty inexperienced, so it's taking me a while to find the syntax error, but i'll get it :)  Thanks Patrick.

Comment: An open brace "{" after function(index)?

Comment: ah yes that is missing

Comment: Ok, last comment to thank you.  I got it all to work, thank you SO much!

Comment: Alternative solution... just put the ajax() call that is located within a loop in a separate function. It's suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22914696/620054 
It worked like a charm for me preventing the issue of the loop variable from just going straight to the last value of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a different callback each time, if you wish to target different entities.

Checkout [closures](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#48), when you are ready, until then try it this way: (Pseudo code)

```
for(...) {
    loadData(i);
}


function loadData(i) {   
   var index = i; 

   $.ajax({
        url: "",
        success : function() {    
               $("#p" + index + "_points").html(data_from_ajax_call);
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: This is what I assumed.  I just ended up with an overwhelming amount of redundancy, because my callback function is rather large, and I basically copy and paste it and just change the variable names in the ().html() call.  I thought surely there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a #P i first then append to parent. Then change the html()?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have at least two options: use a closure, or use forEach().

Fiddle below, containing both. I would use the closure solution, to confuse the Java programmers, and I think that it's more elegant, and more fun.
http://jsfiddle.net/kmiklas/79s8S/4/
**open console to view data**

First, set the id of each row sequentially, like so:

```
<tr id="row1"></tr>
<tr id="row2"></tr>
...
<tr id="rowN"></tr>
```

Then put your row id's into an array.

```
var pointsArray = new Array(999); // whatever length here
for (var i = pointsArray.length; i > -1; i--) {
    pointsArray[i] = 'row' + i;
}
```

CLOSURE SOLUTION:

Now, when retrieving your AJAX data, create an immediate function, passing i every time. This will create a new scope for each callback:

```
for (var i = pointsArray.length; i > -1; i--) {
    (function(j){
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "some.php",
         })
         .done(function( data_from_ajax_call ) {
             $('#' + pointsArray[j]).html(data_from_ajax_call)
         });
    })(i);
}
```

forEach() SOLUTION:

You may also use Array.prototype.forEach(), "The forEach() method executes a provided function once per array element."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
pointsArray.forEach(function(rowName) {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "some.php",
     })
     .done(function( data_from_ajax_call ) {
        $('#' + rowName).html(data_from_ajax_call)
     });
}
```

I'm using jQuery for the AJAX calls. I didn't test them; you have to fiddle with your `data_from_ajax_call` variable. Maybe return a JSON object here.