# Replacing contents of a div using for loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page containing few div tags as follows

```
<div id="dynamic_widget_466" class="dynamic_widget_466"></div>
<div id="dynamic_widget_468" class="dynamic_widget_468"></div>
<div id="dynamic_widget_464" class="dynamic_widget_464"></div>
<div id="dynamic_widget_462" class="dynamic_widget_462"></div>
```

I am trying to get all the values of these div tags into an array variable using jquery and add content to these div tags. The script is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var dynaWidgets = [];
    dynaWidgets = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="dynamic_widget_"]');
    for(var i=0; i<dynaWidgets.length; i++)
    {
        var dynaWidgetId = dynaWidgets[i].id;
        var widgetId = dynaWidgetId.substring(3).split('_')[2];
        console.log('The selected contentId  : ' + dynaWidgetId );
        $.ajax({  
            url: "${CONTEXTPATH}/widgets/dynamic-widget",
            type: "GET",
            data: {    
                contentId: widgetId
            },
            // the type of data we expect back
            dataType : "html",

            success: function( htmlData ) 
            {
                $('#' + dynaWidgetId).html(htmlData);
                console.log('The selected dynaWidgetId ' +i+ ' : ' + dynaWidgetId );
            },

            error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                console.log( "Status: " + status );
                console.dir( xhr );
            },

            complete: function( xhr, status ) {
            },
        });
     }
});
```

Even though I am able to get the values in these divs, the content gets added only to the last div. 
Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: use a closure. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981631/jquery-ajax-inside-a-loop

Comment: Btw. why you not use classes as universal handler like "dynamic_widget", and than just $('.dynamic_widget') to select all dynamic_widget containers

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$("#myid")[0].innerHTML = "test";
```

In simple JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = "test";
```

You can also get content of the div by calling:

```
var content = $("#myid")[0].innerHTML;
```

Or:

```
var content = document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML;
```

Comment: You can use HTML DOM instead of jQuery

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4069982/5287318

Comment: Umh... OP is using a valid method to get a DOM element. The problem is, that `dynaWidgetId` and `i` are not what they expect.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `$.ajax` is default `asynchronous` and the for-loop won't wait for it to complete. Since after loop the value for `dynaWidgetId` is always the last div id, hence only the last div gets the updates.

Try using closures:

```
for(var i=0; i<dynaWidgets.length; i++) {
  (function(dynaWidgetId){
   ... your rest of the code for $.ajax
  })(dynaWidgets[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's eq function to iterate through each div's id, please take a look at [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/budiantoip/ab4fh9ua/).
To use eq function, first use the JQuery selector, the result is JQuery object :

```
dynaWidgets = $(document).find('div[id^="dynamic_widget_"]');
```

Then use the eq function like this :

```
var dynaWidgetId = dynaWidgets.eq(i)[0].id;
```