# ajax is not working inside for loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am creating an dynamic invoice stystem... if i select itemcode then it displays item brand of that item code in my brand input id..if i add new item
then i click on plus button to add new item then i again select a new item code2 then it displays item brand2 of that item code2...so this loop is going on agiain and agian.

my ajax call is not working or some error in ajax code....i cant find the error..if i dint use ajax call only display data of selected var **itemp** then it displays selected data **itemp** in **brand** but using ajax call and find **brand** of selected data **itemp** it didn't works.. please anyone can help me.

here is my javascript ajax call...

```
function getprods(val) {
        for (j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
            var itemp = $('#item_code' + j).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_getitems.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'state_id=' + itemp,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var len = data.length;
                    if (len > 0) {
                        var id = data[0]['id'];
                        var brand = data[0]['brand'];

                        document.getElementById('brand' + j).value = brand;


                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And here is my ajax_getitems.php file

```
<?php

include('conn.php');
$model = $_POST['state_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE code='$model'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$users_arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $brand = $row['brand'];

    $users_arr[] = array("id"    => $id,
                         "brand" => $brand
    );
}

// encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($users_arr);
exit;

?>
```

[image]

[image]

here is my full html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css2/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quotation/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="js2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js2/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="quotation/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js2/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js2/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css2/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
      .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      border-radius: 0;
      }
      /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
      footer {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 25px;
      }
      .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
      margin: auto;
      min-height:200px;
      }
      .navbar-brand
      {
      padding:5px 40px;
      }
      .navbar-brand:hover
      {
      background-color:#ffffff;
      }
      /* Hide the carousel text when the screen is less than 600 pixels wide */
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .carousel-caption {
      display: none; 
      }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .box
      {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1390px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border:1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 0 auto;                
      margin-top:50px;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css2/datepicker.css">
    <script src="js2/bootstrap-datepicker1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#order_date').datepicker({
          format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
          autoclose: true
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('keydown', '.name', function() {

                var id = this.id;
                var splitid = id.split('_');
                var index = splitid[1];

                $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "getDetails.php",
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                search: request.term,request:1
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                response( data );
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                        var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

                        // AJAX
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'getDetails.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {userid:userid,request:2},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success:function(response){

                                var len = response.length;

                                if(len > 0){
                                    var id = response[0]['id'];
                                    var phone = response[0]['phone'];
                                    var email = response[0]['email'];
                                    var address = response[0]['address'];
                                    var gst = response[0]['gst'];

                                    document.getElementById('phone').value = phone;
                                    document.getElementById('email').value = email;
                                    document.getElementById('address').value = address;
                                    document.getElementById('gst').value = gst;

                                }

                            }
                        });

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });


        });

function getproduct(val) {
$.ajax({
url: 'ajax_getproduct.php',
type: 'POST',
data: 'state_id='+val,
dataType: 'json',
success:function(data){
var len = data.length;
if(len > 0){
var id = data[0]['id'];
var item = data[0]['item'];
var subcat = data[0]['subcat'];
var brand = data[0]['brand'];
var model = data[0]['model'];
var specification = data[0]['specification'];
var unitrate = data[0]['unitrate'];
var unitmesure = data[0]['unitmesure'];

document.getElementById('item').value = item;
document.getElementById('subcat').value = subcat;
document.getElementById('brand').value = brand;
document.getElementById('model').value = model;
document.getElementById('Specification').value = specification;
document.getElementById('unitrate1').value = unitrate;
document.getElementById('unitmesure').value = unitmesure;

}
}
});
}
</script>
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <form method="post" id="invoice_form">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2 style="margin-top:10.5px">Create Quotation</h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                      To,<br />
                        <b>RECEIVER (BILL TO)</b><br />
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control name" placeholder="Enter Receiver Name" />
                        <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Billing Address"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Phone No." />
                      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email" />
                      <input type="text" name="gst" id="gst" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="GST" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <table id="invoice-item-table" class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Sr No.</th>
                      <th>Item Code</th>
                                <th>Brand</th>
                      <th>Model</th>
                      <th>Specification</th>
                      <th>Unit Rate</th>
                      <th>Quantity</th>

                      <th>Actual Amt.</th>
                      <th colspan="2">Discount (%)</th>

                      <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
                      <th rowspan="2"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>

                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Rate</th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>Amt.</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><span id="sr_no">1</span></td>
                      <td><select type="text" name="item_code[]" id="item_code" class="form-control input-sm"  onChange="getproduct(this.value);" >
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <?php
    include "conn.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product`";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
    {
    ?>
<option><?php echo $row['code']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
                      </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="item[]" id="item">
             <input type="hidden" name="subcat[]" id="subcat">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" name="brand[]" id="brand" class="form-control input-sm" readonly> 
                      </td>

            <td>
              <input type="text" name="model[]" id="model" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>
            </td>
            <td>
              <textarea name="Specification[]" id="Specification" class="form-control" readonly></textarea>
            </td>
               <td><input type="text" name="unitrate[]" id="unitrate1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm unitrate" />
                <input type="hidden" name="unitmesure" id="unitmesure">
               </td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm number_only qty" /></td>

                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_actual_amount[]" id="order_item_actual_amount1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm order_item_actual_amount" readonly /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_rate[]" id="order_item_tax1_rate1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax1_rate" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_amount[]" id="order_item_tax1_amount1" data-srno="1" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax1_amount" /></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount1" data-srno="1" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_final_amount" /></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <div align="right">
                    <button type="button" name="add_row" id="add_row" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><b>Total</td>
                <td align="right"><b><span id="final_total_amt"></span></b></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                  <input type="hidden" name="total_item" id="total_item" value="1" />
                  <input type="submit" name="create_invoice" id="create_invoice" class="btn btn-info" value="Create" />
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>

              </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
      <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
        var count = 1;


        $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
          count++;

          $('#total_item').val(count);
          var html_code = '';
          html_code += '<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
          html_code += '<td><span id="sr_no">'+count+'</span></td>';

         html_code += '<td><select name="item_code[]" id="item_code'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm item_code"><option></option><?php $sql='Select * from product'; $run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){ echo '<option>'.$row['code'].'</option>'; } ?></select><input type="hidden" name="item[]" id="item'+count+'"><input type="hidden" name="subcat[]" id="subcat'+count+'"></td>';


          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="brand[]" id="brand'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" readonly></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="model[]" id="model'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" readonly></td>';

          html_code += '<td><textarea name="Specification[]" id="Specification'+count+'" class="form-control" readonly></textarea></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="unitrate[]" id="unitrate'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only unitrate" /><input type="hidden" name="unitmesure[]" id="unitmesure'+count+'"></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only qty" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_actual_amount[]" id="order_item_actual_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm order_item_actual_amount" readonly /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_rate[]" id="order_item_tax1_rate'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax1_rate" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_amount[]" id="order_item_tax1_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax1_amount" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_final_amount" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><button type="button" name="remove_row" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_row">X</button></td>';
          html_code += '</tr>';
          $('#invoice-item-table').append(html_code);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function(){
          var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
          var total_item_amount = $('#order_item_final_amount'+row_id).val();
          var final_amount = $('#final_total_amt').text();
          var result_amount = parseFloat(final_amount) - parseFloat(total_item_amount);
          $('#final_total_amt').text(result_amount);
          $('#row_id_'+row_id).remove();
          count--;
          $('#total_item').val(count);
        });





        function cal_final_total(count)
        {
          var final_item_total = 0;
          for(j=1; j<=count; j++)
          {
            var quantity = 0;
            var price = 0;
            var actual_amount = 0;
            var tax1_rate = 0;
            var tax1_amount = 0;
            var tax2_rate = 0;
            var tax2_amount = 0;
            var tax3_rate = 0;
            var tax3_amount = 0;
            var item_total = 0;
            quantity = $('#unitrate'+j).val();
            if(quantity > 0)
            {
              price = $('#qty'+j).val();
              if(price > 0)
              {
                actual_amount = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
                $('#order_item_actual_amount'+j).val(actual_amount);
                tax1_rate = $('#order_item_tax1_rate'+j).val();
                if(tax1_rate > 0)
                {
                  tax1_amount = -(parseFloat(actual_amount)*parseFloat(tax1_rate)/100);
                  $('#order_item_tax1_amount'+j).val(tax1_amount);
                }

                item_total = parseFloat(actual_amount) + parseFloat(tax1_amount) + parseFloat(tax2_amount) + parseFloat(tax3_amount);
                final_item_total = parseFloat(final_item_total) + parseFloat(item_total);
                $('#order_item_final_amount'+j).val(item_total);
              }
            }
          }
          $('#final_total_amt').text(final_item_total);
        }

function getprods()
{
 for(j=1; j<=count; j++)
{
var itemp = $('#item_code'+j).val();
$.ajax({
url: 'ajax_getitems.php',
type: 'POST',
data: 'state_id='+itemp,
dataType: 'json',
success:function(data){
var len = data.length;
if(len > 0){
var id = data[0]['id'];
var brand = data[0]['brand'];

document.getElementById('brand'+j).value = brand;


}

}
});
}
}


        $(document).on('blur', '.qty', function(){
          cal_final_total(count);
        });

        $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_tax1_rate', function(){
          cal_final_total(count);
        });

         $(document).on('change', '.item_code', function(){
              getprods(this.value);
        });



        $('#create_invoice').click(function(){
          if($.trim($('#order_receiver_name').val()).length == 0)
          {
            alert("Please Enter Reciever Name");
            return false;
          }

          if($.trim($('#order_no').val()).length == 0)
          {
            alert("Please Enter Invoice Number");
            return false;
          }

          if($.trim($('#order_date').val()).length == 0)
          {
            alert("Please Select Invoice Date");
            return false;
          }

          for(var no=1; no<=count; no++)
          {
            if($.trim($('#item_name'+no).val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Enter Item Name");
              $('#item_name'+no).focus();
              return false;
            }

            if($.trim($('#unitrate'+no).val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Enter Quantity");
              $('#unitrate'+no).focus();
              return false;
            }

            if($.trim($('#qty'+no).val()).length == 0)
            {
              alert("Please Enter Price");
              $('#qty'+no).focus();
              return false;
            }

          }

          $('#invoice_form').submit();

        });

      });
      </script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.number_only').keypress(function(e){
return isNumbers(e, this);      
});
function isNumbers(evt, element) 
{
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (
(charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&      // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
return false;
return true;
}
});


</script>
  </body>
</html>


<?php
include('conn2.php');
if(isset($_POST['create_invoice']))
{
  $order_receiver_name=$_POST['order_receiver_name'];
  $order_receiver_address=$_POST['order_receiver_address'];
  $order_no=$_POST['order_no'];
  $order_date=$_POST['order_date'];

  $order_total_before_tax = 0;
  $order_total_tax1 = 0;
  $order_total_tax2 = 0;
  $order_total_tax3 = 0;
  $order_total_tax = 0;
  $order_total_after_tax = 0;

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $current = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_order`(`order_no`, `order_date`, `order_receiver_name`, `order_receiver_address`, `order_total_before_tax`, `order_total_tax1`, `order_total_tax2`, `order_total_tax3`, `order_total_tax`, `order_total_after_tax`, `order_datetime`) VALUES ('$order_no','$order_date','$order_receiver_name','$order_receiver_address','$order_total_before_tax','$order_total_tax1','$order_total_tax2','$order_total_tax3','$order_total_tax','$order_total_after_tax','$current')";

  $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if($run)

      {
          echo "<script>alert('Inserted Successfully')</script>";
      }
      else{
          echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
      }

 $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

  for($count=0; $count<$_POST["total_item"]; $count++)
  {
    $item_name =  $_POST['item_name'][$count];
    $unitrate =  $_POST['unitrate'][$count];
    $qty =  $_POST['qty'][$count];
    $order_item_actual_amount =  $_POST['order_item_actual_amount'][$count];
    $order_item_tax1_rate =  $_POST['order_item_tax1_rate'][$count];
    $order_item_tax1_amount =  $_POST['order_item_tax1_amount'][$count];
    $order_item_tax2_rate =  $_POST['order_item_tax2_rate'][$count];
    $order_item_tax2_amount =  $_POST['order_item_tax2_amount'][$count];
    $order_item_tax3_rate =  $_POST['order_item_tax3_rate'][$count];
    $order_item_tax3_amount =  $_POST['order_item_tax3_amount'][$count];
    $order_item_final_amount =  $_POST['order_item_final_amount'][$count];

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `tbl_order_item`(`order_id`, `item_name`, `order_item_quantity`, `order_item_price`, `order_item_actual_amount`, `order_item_tax1_rate`, `order_item_tax1_amount`, `order_item_tax2_rate`, `order_item_tax2_amount`, `order_item_tax3_rate`, `order_item_tax3_amount`, `order_item_final_amount`) VALUES ('$last_id','$item_name','$order_item_quantity','$order_item_price','$order_item_actual_amount','$order_item_tax1_rate','$order_item_tax1_amount','$order_item_tax2_rate','$order_item_tax2_amount','$order_item_tax3_rate','$order_item_tax3_amount','$order_item_final_amount')";

    $run2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

  if($run2)

    {
      echo "<script>alert('inserted successfully')</script>";
    }
    else{
      echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    $order_total_before_tax = $order_total_before_tax + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_actual_amount"][$count]));

        $order_total_tax1 = $order_total_tax1 + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_tax1_amount"][$count]));

        $order_total_tax2 = $order_total_tax2 + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_tax2_amount"][$count]));

        $order_total_tax3 = $order_total_tax3 + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_tax3_amount"][$count]));

        $order_total_after_tax = $order_total_after_tax + floatval(trim($_POST["order_item_final_amount"][$count]));



  }
  $order_total_tax = $order_total_tax1 + $order_total_tax2 + $order_total_tax3;

  $sql3 = "UPDATE `tbl_order` SET `order_total_before_tax`='$order_total_before_tax',`order_total_tax1`='$order_total_tax1',`order_total_tax2`='$order_total_tax2',`order_total_tax3`='$order_total_tax3',`order_total_tax`='$order_total_tax',`order_total_after_tax`='$order_total_after_tax' WHERE `order_id`='$last_id'";

  $run3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

  if($run3)

    {
      echo "<script>alert('inserted successfully')</script>";
    }
    else{
      echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: show the networks tab screenshot so i can see the ajax call response

Comment: okk..i have edited it...see in the screen shot..

Comment: No i was talking about networks tab screenshot in the chrome developers tool. That networks tab gives you information about the call made by the page and its response code. Also check if there is no error in the console.

Comment: Do you know how to use your browser's console to see errors generated from you script?

Comment: see ...i have edited now.

Comment: In your `getprods()` you are passing `val` but then you never use it.  What value are you passing to your function?  Then in your for loop you are using `count`, but count has no value.. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: var itemp is similar value that i passing in to getproducts()

Comment: No...You are passing a variable called `val`!  what is it?  It is never again mentioned in your code.

Comment: Firstly, I don't like the fact that you are using a `for loop`. I would prefer you send all the data and do the for looping on the server side (php). Secondly, what is the value of the `var count`...?

Comment: On a sidenote: you are making multiple ajax calls to the same script. It is way more efficient to first collect the data in js, then make only one ajax call, process in php, send back the data and distribute over the input fields.

Comment: You need to take a step back and look at your code line by line.  There is most likely no reason to loop over your ajax statement.  You need to rethink this entire approach.

Comment: if i used val in data: 'state_id=' + val, that is also not working for me  @Joseph_J

Comment: var count is if i add a new line then it count 2 then again click add new then it counts 3...so it is count++ @ChukwuemekaInya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.ajax() inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981631/jquery-ajax-inside-a-loop)

Comment: no i didn't get the ans from it @AravindhGopi

Comment: Let's see your html too.

Comment: i have edited my full html code now..@ChukwuemekaInya

Answer (score 1):

Edit your php file as below.

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
$model = $_POST['state_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE code='$model'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
?>
```

Then edit your ajax part like below,

```
function getprods(itemp) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_getitems.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'state_id':itemp },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(json, function (index, item) {
                var id = item.id;
                var brand = item.brand;
                document.getElementById('brand' + index).value = brand;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any relation between you val and itemp ? cant your get all items using a single val, and get those all values at once ? I just edited my code above try giving one value to itemp and see the returned result, if you look in to this, you can have your problem resolved, I cannot give you the final best solution because i dont have enough idea about your full data structure.

Answer (score 1):

adding property async: false inside ajax may solve this issue.

```
 $.ajax({
          url:"get_response_filter.php",
          method: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
j <= count;
```

But where is 'count' var?

Comment: i have declared count var in my javascript code above getproduct function $(document).ready(function(){
        var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
        var count = 1;

Comment: Then count is out of scope.

Comment: 'count' has Global scope ... It's outside the function... Should be accessible from inside a function...

Comment: Please pay attention on this: .... var count =1; ..... then inside your `for` loop, you have... j=1.... your condition is j<=count..... now your `for` loop will iterate only once because j++ will increase the value of `j` but var `count` will remain the same, having a value of 1; for the second iteration condition will be false every time. Then the question is why do you need a for loop when it runs only once?

Comment: i need for loop for add new product and it is again and again added @TariqulIslam

Comment: Yes now I have found `count++` in your updated code which I was looking for.... Previously there was no increment of `count`... That's why I was asking for attention.